# How to map Collections in C# that support 2 ways of Deserialisation?

Tags: c#, json, collections, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to call an external WebAPI and the input has similar shape as the output. I want to reuse the same type of objects for both input and output.

Indeed there is an easy way out to just have request and response models like following to add extra layer in `Attachments` property:

```
request = new { MessageText = "text", Attachments = new {Attachment = attachments }};
response = new { MessageText = "text", Attachments = attachments };
```

But I'm interested if these two models can be represented by single class but serialized to different schema compared to deserialization. Ideally looking for some attributes on properties, but open to custom converters or anything else.

Details:

Input json for the WebAPI must be like this :

```json
    {
      "MessageText": "text",
      "Attachments": {
        "Attachment": [
          {
            "FileName": "file1"
          },
          {
            "FileName": "file2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

but when the WebAPI returns the same object in result, it returns this :

```json
    {
      "MessageText": "text",
      "Attachments": [
        {
          "FileName": "file1"
        },
        {
          "FileName": "file2"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I don't know why the WebAPI require a level "Attachment" in input, and does not return in Output...
Of course, I don't have any control over the code for the WebAPI.

How can I map my DTO classes using C# ?
They must pass these 3 unit tests ?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestJsonCollectionSerialisation
{
    private void TestMethodDeSerialization(string json)
    {
        var actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, actual.Attachments.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("file1", actual.Attachments[0].FileName);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodDeSerialization1()
    {
        const string JSON1 = "{\"MessageText\":\"text\",\"Attachments\":[{\"FileName\":\"file1\"},{\"FileName\":\"file2\"}]}";
        TestMethodDeSerialization(JSON1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodDeSerialization2()
    {
        const string JSON2 = "{\"MessageText\":\"text\",\"Attachments\":{\"Attachment\":[{\"FileName\":\"file1\"},{\"FileName\":\"file2\"}]}}";
        TestMethodDeSerialization(JSON2);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodSerialization()
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.MessageText = "text";
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment() { FileName = "file1" });
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment() { FileName = "file2" });
        string actual = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        Assert.AreEqual("{\"MessageText\":\"text\",\"Attachments\":{\"Attachment\":[{\"FileName\":\"file1\"},{\"FileName\":\"file2\"}]}}", actual);
    }
}
```

The following DTO classes pass the first Unit test, but not the 2 last.

```
public class Message
{
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public Attachments Attachments { get; set; } = new Attachments();
}

public class Attachment
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

public class Attachments : List<Attachment> { }
```

How can I do to have all unit tests green please ?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible by using standard `JsonConverter` with attributes of Json.NET.

You can write your own `JsonConverter<Message>` for that purpose, but it is better to have both request and response models because they can be changed independently of each other, so you will need to write a more complex converter.

Sample `MessageJsonConverter` which will pass your tests

```
public class MessageJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Message>
{
    public override Message ReadJson(JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, [AllowNull] Message existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        var message = existingValue ?? new Message();
        while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            var propertyName = (string) reader.Value;
            if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(message.MessageText), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                reader.Read();
                message.MessageText = (string) reader.Value;
            }
            else if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(message.Attachments), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
                {
                    message.Attachments = serializer.Deserialize<Attachments>(reader);
                }
                else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    var subPropertyName = (string) reader.Value;
                    if (subPropertyName.Equals("Attachment", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        reader.Read(); // now JsonToken.StartArray
                        message.Attachments = serializer.Deserialize<Attachments>(reader); // now JsonToken.EndArray
                        reader.Read(); // now JsonToken.PropertyName or JsonToken.EndObject
                        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
                            throw new JsonSerializationException($"Additional properties in [{propertyName}]");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new JsonSerializationException($"Unknown property [{propertyName}.{subPropertyName}]");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException($"Unknown property [{propertyName}]");
            }
        }

        return message;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, [AllowNull] Message value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(Message.MessageText));
            writer.WriteValue(value.MessageText);

            writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(Message.Attachments));
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName("Attachment");
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Attachments);
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

**Note:** This class can (I am almost sure it does) contains bugs, so you need to write more tests for a corner cases with nulls, etc..

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't technically answer your exact question, but I would do it with additional methods to convert to/from request and response.

Modifying the serialization rules to be different for request and response would be more work and to me violates the [principal of least astonishment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment). This way, any engineer reviewing the code for the `Message` class will immediately understand what is going on.

```
class Message
{
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public Attachment[] Attachments { get; set; }

    public string ToRequest()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { MessageText = this.MessageText, Attachments = new { Attachment = this.Attachments }});
    }

    static public Message FromResponse(string input)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(input);
    }
}
```

To deserialize:

```
var actual = Message.FromResponse(json);
```

To serialize:

```
var json = actual.ToRequest();
```